# c#/Razor: How do I reference a user defined function from a .cshtml page?

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015, user-defined-functions

I have a Functions.cshtml file with all user defined functions:

```
@functions {
.
   public static string doSomething(string aString, string anotherString) {
   ...
   }
.
}
```

In another myPage.cshtml page, I reference
`doSomething:Functions.doSomething("dummy", "AnotherString");`

When I run this from within VS 2015, the method is referenced and executed. However, when I deploy my app to my website and try executing myPage.cshtml, I get the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'ASP.Functions' does not contain a
>   definition for 'doSomething'.

How can I get the web page to function as if it's running in the VS 2015 IDE?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't best practice to keep all of your functions in a cshtml file. If add a standard C# class in your App_Code folder with all of those functions then you'll be able to access them all with no imports. For example, if doSomething is static and the class is called Functions then you can call it like:

```
@Functions.doSomething("dummy", "AnotherString");
```

To answer the actual question, I believe you can't call functions from other cshtml pages if they aren't in App_Code.